# How Cache busting in ASP.net work with firefox?

Tags: asp.net, firefox, caching, browser-cache

I have implemented cache busting by following this article [cache busting in asp.net](https://madskristensen.net/blog/cache-busting-in-aspnet)
and did some testings for chrome and firefox browsers.

I've opened the cache folders of both browsers and checked the cache item count. 
Once I do a modification to a css file and refresh the browser window and after checked the cache item count. Chrome's cache item count remains same. But firefox cache count increases.

What I've understood is - chrome it updates the existing cache object and firefox creates new cache object once a file is modified.

What I want to know is is this the default behaviour of firefox or if the cache busting is not working properly for firefox?

Answer (score 0):

if you implemented as the example then the number on this line (that represents the version of the file) will change on all, and all browser will re-read the css file if you change it.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/content/v-634933238684083941/site.css" />
```

If you not use this version number, and you just have a static file like this css

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/content/site.css" />
```

then the browser may re-read it in some cases, for example if you force to reload the page by press the reload+shift, or even if you just reload, if the browser clears their cache, if he check the date time of the file... you need to make a lot more inspection to fully understand why is not keep the cache - browsers try to smart recognize if the file is change and reload it.

Comment: Yes I urls have version number and I've used chromcacheview and mzcache view. From them I've understood that  chrome updates the existing cache object and firefox creates new cache object once a file is modified.

Comment: @sav So whats the bid different I do not understand... the results on the page is the same

Comment: yes but my concern is if firefox saves new cache objects for every modifications  won't that be a performance issue? Since there existes old cache + new cache objects?

Comment: @sav firefox bealive that the file site.css maybe exist two times, so its keep both of them. If you can try to use this kind of cache -> `/site.css?v=288372991` Adding a parameter at the end.